# Display definition of the term searched for - above search results

Tags: search

Beginning a search on google with 'what is psych'... triggers auto completion with 4 suggested phrases - arrow down through each and you will see its definition appear above its pertaining results:
[image: auto completed search terms with definition above results]

How can I add a definition of the terms (if available) above the results? Ideally would like to use auto complete. I've attempted to achieve this with the Google custom search engine and Google site search modules. Unfortunately, the Google Dictionary service appears to [no longer be supported by Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/XnWKqUGIrfM;context-place=starred).

I explored another option such as using Solr search api and coding a second custom call from a definition source such as Wordnik and then combining that result with the Solr results. I think this may be feasible but not sure yet how will combine the results.

How could I combine search results to include a definition and/or is there a better way to include a definition of what the user may be searching for, above the actual results?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was necessary to use Wordnik api (or similar) to get the definition service that I required. So I've written a module to handle the api and show definition/image for the searched terms if available.

After talking to Google support and verifying my research that google no longer provides a definition service (they did back in 2011) to private websites, I realized it best to abandon the idea of using the google custom search engine. Instead I've setup Solr which is a bit more work but much more custom.